# file_get_contents doesn't work if there is a dot(.) in the folder in Windows platform

Tags: php, windows, directory, file-get-contents, filepath

I am using Windows platform.
If I place myFile.pdf inside the abc@xyz.com then the below code doesn't work-

```
file_get_contents('C:\Apache24\htdocs\portal\abc@xyz.com\myFile.pdf')
```

If I place myFile.pdf inside the abc@xyzcom then the below code works-

```
file_get_contents('C:\Apache24\htdocs\portal\abc@xyzcom\myFile.pdf')
```

So the conclusion is - If there is a dot(.) in the folder name, then `file_get_contents` doesn't work as expected.

Any idea how to escape the (.) in the folder name in Windows platform?

Comment: You have `/var/www/...` on a windows platform? ok, possible.....

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error using php 5.6.14/win10.

Comment: @VolkerK I am sorry about /var/www, I just gave an example with that path. I will edit it now. I am using PHP 5.5 Windows Server 2012

Answer (score 2):

Not an aswer (yet):
Please try

```
<?php
$path = 'C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\portal\\abc@xyz.com\\myFile.pdf';
checkPath($path);

function checkPath($path) {
    $d = dirname($path);
    if ( '/'===$d || '\\'===$d || $path===$d ) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        checkPath($d);
        echo 
            file_exists($path) ? '+':'-',
            is_dir($path) ? 'd' : ' ',
            is_readable($path) ? 'r' : ' ',
            ' | ', $path, 
        "<br />\r\n";
    }
}
```

and [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34102585/edit) the output to your question text.

Comment: Thanks for the post. For this path = C:\Apache24\htdocs\portal\abc@xyz.com\myFile.pdf I got the result as `-` with the code which you mentioned.I don't understand why it shows that the file doesn't exist.Read permissions are there for that file.

Comment: But for the path `C:\Apache24\htdocs\portal\abc@xyz.com` it showed `+dr | `? Or where did it start to show only `-   | `?